# Need of a call(), apply() and bind() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have read lot of theory regarding `call()`, `apply()` and `bind()`.

I am not able to understand if we can call method directly why we need `call()` , `apply()` or `bind()`?

Can somebody explain in laymen terms and little in terms of JavaScript?

Comment: What don't you understand from the Stack Overflow posts you've already read? You're most likely going to receive similar explanations which you won't be able to follow unless you explain what you don't understand in particular. Understanding these methods requires some understanding of the `this` keyword, maybe that's what you're not following?  (if so, you can check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for it)

Comment: Thanks you  @NickParsons . everywhere it is explained what is diff in call() , bind() and apply(), but did not got question where it is mentioned what is the specific purpose.

Comment: Using `call` and `apply` you can borrow a method from another object. Notice that the first argument of both `call` and `apply` is what object you want its `this` to be. For example if you have an object `employee` and another object `people` and there is a method called `employee.fullName()` that does not exist in `people` you can do `employee.fullName.call(people)` which would be like calling `people.fullName()` even though people does not have the `fullName()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the flexibility offered by Javascript, an object and it's method don't have to be coupled with each other.

Given following object 'a' with a member method 'play'

```
var a = { play: function (content) { console.log("what is this:", this, content)} }
```

Use

```
a.play('Hello')
```

Is equivalent to

```
a.play.call(a, 'Hello')
```

As for your question why need the second way 'call'. Because 'call' gives you a way to call something else instead of 'this', which is 'a' in the example above, so you can do:

```
a.play.call(document, 'Hello')
```

About 'apply', it's just another version of 'call', which needs you to pass arguments as an array instead of comma separated parameters. To use apply, you do:

```
a.play.apply(a, ['Hello'])
```

As for 'bind', it is to link a function with a 'this' object at first, then get a returned callable object, which you can either call with the rest arguments directly, or pass it into anything else to be called later.

A typical 'bind' use case is React component's event handler. To define an event handler to be passed into a component. You need to use 'bind' in a React class component like this:

```
handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
```

Then, in render function:

```
<Button onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

Check https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html for the full information.

Comment: Wow..thank you so much @Rob . I understood completely.